# Can I pass python **kwargs to parent class from sub?

Tags: python, keyword-argument

I'd like to do something like this:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
       """ 
       return exception if certain arguments not set
       """

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
       super(B, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

Basically, each subclass will require certain arguments to be properly instantiated. They are the same params across the board. I only want to do the checking of these arguments once. If I can do this from the parent **init**() - all the better.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Sure.  This is not an uncommon pattern:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, foo, bar=3):
        self.foo = foo
        self.bar = bar

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, quux=6, **kwargs):
        super(B, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.quux = quux

B(foo=1, quux=4)
```

This also insulates you a little from [`super` shenanigans](https://fuhm.net/super-harmful/): now `A`'s argspec can change without requiring any edits to `B`, and diamond inheritance is a little less likely to break.

Comment: Note that you can instantiate an `A` object with `A(1,3)` but you cannot instantiate a `B` object with `B(1,3)` or even `B(1,3,4)`

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely. Parameter and keyword expansion will work naturally when fed into parameter and keyword arguments.